# connect socket.io android client through a reverse proxy server to socket server

Tags: android, node.js, sockets, nginx, socket.io

I'm trying to connect to a socket.io server running behind a Nginx reverse proxy. I have Nginx proxy server running with https config `https://api.xxx.com`. The node js socket.io server is running on another server with http config `http://a.b.c.d:8081/app/v2`.

In android side as a socket client, I'm using `implementation 'com.github.nkzawa: socket.io-client:0.3.0`.

Proxy is configured like this :

```
location /app/v2 {

            proxy_cache apicache;
            proxy_cache_revalidate on;
            proxy_cache_min_uses 2;
            proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout updating http_500 http_502
                          http_503 http_504;
            proxy_cache_lock on;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_cache_control;
            add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
            proxy_cache_methods GET;
            proxy_cache_valid 200 302 2s;
            proxy_cache_valid 404 1m;

            proxy_pass http://a.b.c.d:8081/app/v2;

            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

    }
```

Node js Server :

```
socketio = socketio.listen(server);
socketio.set('transports', ['websocket']);
socketio.of('/app/v2/socketio/livefeed/').on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log("device connected");
    socket.emit('clientAction','connected');
    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log("device disconnected");
        socket.emit('clientAction','disconnected');
    });
});
```

While trying to connect the android app to socket like this

```
`try { 
    mSocket = IO.socket("https://api.xxx.com/app/v2/socketio/livefeed/");
 } catch (URISyntaxException e) { 
    Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(e)); 
 } 
 mSocket.connect();`
```

The socket client is not connecting to the socket.io server.
How should I connect android socket client to socket server behind the proxy server?

Comment: Provide your complete nginx config

Comment: updated the nginx.conf @TarunLalwani

Comment: If you connect directly to `http://a.b.c.d:8081/app/v2`, does it work?

Comment: Yes by directly connecting to url works perfectly. I also added the server socket code @TarunLalwani

Comment: Can you change `location /app/v2 {` to `location /app/v2/socketio {` and append the same in proxy_pass also and see if it works?

Comment: still not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174659/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-sasuke).

Comment: what's the error message?

Comment: Android Socket client show nothing as the error, just return `socket.isConnected == false`

Comment: `16024#16024: *30617 open socket #1901 left in connection 2077` this is logging in error.log of Nginx. @FaisalMemon

Comment: Please change Proxy pass 'proxy_pass http://a.b.c.d:8081;' and try  because nginx doesn't create URL it uses same. basically remove /app/v2 from proxypass

Answer (score 0):

The url you're using is the issue, since you might need to pass it to proxy anyways for your routing purposes please try the following in your nginx conf. Hope this helps.

```
location ~ /app/v2/(?<section>.*) {

        proxy_cache apicache;
        proxy_cache_revalidate on;
        proxy_cache_min_uses 2;
        proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout updating http_500 http_502
                      http_503 http_504;
        proxy_cache_lock on;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_cache_control;
        add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
        proxy_cache_methods GET;
        proxy_cache_valid 200 302 2s;
        proxy_cache_valid 404 1m;

        proxy_pass http://a.b.c.d:8081/app/v2/$section;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;



}
```

Comment: I don't think url is the issue because others api behind the proxy running on same server(http://a.b.c.d:8081/app/v2/) is working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I've faced such problem with sockets.

In my case, it was solved by adding this in `nginx.conf`

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    ''      close;
}
```